# Automatic Date Format Conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, date

I have a column of data type `date` in SQL Server 2012. All the dates currently in this column have format `yyyy-mm-dd`. When I attempt to update a row explicitly:

```
Update Table 
set column = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
Where rowid = X
```

...the script runs successfully, but the format `yyyy-mm-dd` persists. What could possibly be causing this automatic conversion? Is there somewhere a format can be stored for this `date` column?

There are other `date` columns in different tables where this does not occur, so I believe it is specific to this column. The other columns appear as `mm/dd/yyyy`. I haven't tried updating these columns to show as `yyyy-mm-dd`, but, they are the same data type and I could discern no difference between the two.

I just tinker around on these databases. Do not administer and am a novice with SQL (obviously). Could you name one or two settings I can investigate?

Comment: Try and leave your date formatting to your reporting application, not your data storage application.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server date/time types are stored in a binary format, **not as strings**.

Values of these types are only translated to (or from) a **particular string representation** when something (e.g. a `SELECT` query) asks for it, implicitly or explicitly.

Client software (e.g. SSMS) may also retrieve the raw data then format it as a string locally, according to its own rules. The string representation chosen depends on a number (server and client) configuration settings.

To avoid ambiguity and possible errors, always use `CONVERT`, `TRY_CONVERT` with a **specific style** parameter, or `FORMAT` with a culture code to convert to or from a specific string representation.

See the following product documentation pages:

- [`CAST` and `CONVERT` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- [`TRY_CONVERT` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [`FORMAT` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

For example:

```
DECLARE @T AS table (date_value date NOT NULL);

-- Add a date value using a specific string format
INSERT @T (date_value)
VALUES (CONVERT(date, '20161219', 112)) -- 112 = yyyymmdd

-- Display the date in two different string representations
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), T.date_value, 120), -- 120 = yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)
    FORMAT(T.date_value, 'D', 'de-DE')       -- Standard long date pattern (German)
FROM @T AS T;
```

Output:

[image: Results]

Note that `FORMAT` is considerably more flexible than `CONVERT`, but is correspondingly slower. For most uses, `CONVERT` is preferable.